# Xcode 8.2.1 CPU Load is HIgh

Tags: xcode, performance, load, xcode8, cpu-usage

Im experiencing high CPU Load when I open my Xcode and
it bothers me because it affects my productivity, my xcode keeps on compiling when i type a code and it also takes time to give the suggested code (e.g) **Intellisense**

This is the CPU load when I open Xcode, 
look at the graph. I dont know if this normal or what.
[image]

Here is my device specification

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem in Xcode 8.3.3. Restart helps, but I still don't understand the reason.

Comment: I not sure if the new beta version of Xcode will fix this issue, but we should give it a try for *Xcode 9*